# Use Include and Extends always showing error and can't be loaded

Tags: symfony, twig, template-engine, templating, twig-extension

I have `base.twig` like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=996">
        <meta name="description" content="{{ meta_description }}">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="{{ assets_url }}img/ico.png">
        <title>{{ meta_title }}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ assets_url }}css/main.css">
        <script src="{{ assets_url }}js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ assets_url }}js/plugin.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ assets_url }}js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        {% include 'partials/header.twig' %}

    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to import `header.twig` in `base.twig` but not working and still getting error message like this :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: A template that extends another one cannot include contents outside Twig blocks. Did you forget to put the contents inside a {% block %} tag?
```

And this is `header.twig` file :

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

<!-- my content header is here -->
```

What did i miss? What's wrong with my code ?, I read in https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/. Please give me solution or something. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove extending from `header.html.twig`. Read [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#template-inheritance-and-layouts).

Template which extends some parent template cannot be included in the parent, because there is an infinite loop. 
If you want to separate part of code, just split it to another twig and include it.

But if you want to create independent template which bases on another then the template have to extends `base.html.twig`.

E.g. `articles.html.twig` which extends `base.html.twig`, which has included `header.html.twig`.

In code:

**base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% include 'partials/header.html.twig' %}

        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**header.html.twig**

```
<div>
   my header
</div>
```

**articles.html.twig**

```
{% extends base.html.twig %}

{% block body %}
    <div>
        articles content
    </div> 
{% endblock %}
```

Now, your rendered `articles.html.twig` from your controller, should look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            my header
        </div>

        <div>
            articles content
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But header.twig not in <head> tag. I mean, header.twig is header content like search, menu navigation etc

Comment: Yeaahhh its working. Thanks sir :) I have a question , if i put include inside header.twig, i make file php or still in base.php ?

Comment: You can include one template to another infinetely nested. But you have to remember about infinite loop. Any child cannot include parent template. E.g. your base can include header/body/footer templates, header can include search/login templates and in fine login can include user and term-of-service templates. BUT search cannot include header, because the header template is parent for search.

Comment: But I'm not sure if I understood your question.

Comment: Yes, i understand your explanation. May I give you one sample in the next question ?

Comment: check this out :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817886/using-nested-include-twig

Answer (score 2):

your base.twig should look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=996">
        <meta name="description" content="{{ meta_description }}">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="{{ assets_url }}img/ico.png">
        <title>{{ meta_title }}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ assets_url }}css/main.css">
        <script src="{{ assets_url }}js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ assets_url }}js/plugin.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ assets_url }}js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

and in your header.twig file

```
{% extends 'base.twig' %}
{% block body %}
// your content goes here
{% endblock %}
```

i tried it will work fine...

otherwise if you want to include the header in the base file. then just add the

```
{% include 'partials/header.twig' %}
```

inside the block body in the base file.

Comment: I tried your script , can loaded. But if i add "footer.twig" with the same way (use block). My base file can't stop loading and output many header