# Using Nested Include Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, templating, twig-extension, templating-engine

in my `header.twig` :

```
<ul class="nav list-unstyled">
    {% for item in data %}
       {% include 'partials/item/header/item-nav.twig' %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

in my item-nav.twig

```
<li><a href="{{ data.url }}">{{ data.menu_name }}</a></li>
```

header.twig is included in base.twig. I rendered base.twig in base.php file. Where I can add data `array`to process `data.url` and `data.name`? in base.php ? or i rendered file php again ? Thank you.

base.php

```
include __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$renderer = new \Resilient\TwigRenderer(__DIR__ . '/../vemale-beta-desktop/templates/', ['debug'    => true]);

$renderer->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());

$faker = Faker\Factory::create();

$data = [
    'assets_url' => 'http://devel.merdeka.com/ui/2017/april/Vemale/',
    'meta_title' => 'Vemale Beta',
    'meta_description' => 'Vemale Beta Desktop',
    'data' => ['menu_name' => 'PARENTING']
];

/*foreach ( range(0, 10) as $k ) {
    $data['data'][] = [ 'title' => $faker->sentence() ];
}*/

$response = $renderer->render(new \Zend\Diactoros\Response(),'base.twig', $data);

$emitter = new Zend\Diactoros\Response\SapiEmitter();

$emitter->emit($response);
```

Comment: Show your controller action which renders the template and the templates code (only associated fragments).

Comment: I already edit my code

Comment: Very  unclear what you want to do here. Every variable passed towards `base.twig` is available in the ìncluded template

Answer (score -1):

**header.twig**

```
<ul>
    {% for item in data %}
        {{ include('partials/item-nav.twig') }}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**item-nav.twig**

```
<li><a href="{{ item.<some-property> }}">{{ item.<other-property> }}</a></li>
```

Comment: The variable `item` is known inside the include whether you pass it explicit or not. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/a301am)